# С++ использование наследников конкретных классов в шаблоне

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, шаблоны-с++

Подскажите, есть ли в C++ механизм задания шаблона, для которого пользователь может указать только ограниченное число классов - классов, которые являются наследниками определенного класса, т.е. что-то типа

```
template<class object [implemented] base_class> func()
{}

class x: public base_class
{};

class y
{};

func<x>(); // все ок
func<y>(); // ошибка
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
class base_class
{
};

template<
    typename object,
    typename = enable_if_t<is_base_of_v<base_class,object>>
>
void func()
{}

class x: public base_class
{};

class y
{};


int main()
{
    func<x>();
    func<y>();
}
```

Посмотрите, [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) много разных свойств, которые можно проверять.

Comment: Harry, а короткой встроенной команды в C++ не появилось? Выглядит конечно круто, но уж очень страшно :)

Comment: Не слышал :) В принципе, в язык все хотят, но никак не введут *концепты* (см., например, [эту книгу](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9500296-8-4.html)), но сказать, что они будут сильно короче - не думаю...

Comment: @Zhihar Вы хотите увидеть концепты. Они появятся только в С++20. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Requires_expressions

Answer (score 0):

Такие трюки обычно обозначают аббревиатурой [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error). Известны они с незапамятных времен, но начиная с C++11 в языке и STL появилось много инструментов для этого.

Например, так:

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<base_class, T>> func();

    // enable_if_t is a using-alias for enable_if::type
    // which is only defined in case condition is true
    // and is void by default
```

Немного изменив тип функции, можно обойтись и без enable_if:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct Base {};

template<typename T>
decltype(static_cast<Base const &>(std::declval<T>()), int{}) omg (T &&)
{
    return 42;
}

int omg(...) { return 314; }

struct T: Base {};
struct U {};

int main() {
    std::cout << omg(T{}) << '\n';
    std::cout << omg(U{}) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class object> func()
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<base_class, object>, "sorry :(");
}
```

Только это, как говорят, не SFINAE-friendly, поэтому перегрузку функции сделать не получится.